# net core / IdentityServer : unable to logout

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

In my Blazor app, I use the Identity-server (identityserver.io) as an external service to manage the authorization.

The login works correctly, but when I try to log out, and then try to log in, I'm directly logged-in without asking for any user name/pwd ! I'm searching since a week without finding any solution !

I use the following code :

```
    var props = (returnUrl is null) ? null : new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = returnUrl
    };

    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc", props);
```

I have also try to delete all the cookies, but HttpContext.Request.Cookies has no cookie !

I have also check the following links:
https://mcguirev10.com/2018/01/26/signoutasync-and-identity-server-cookies.html
But I don't see anythin that help !

FYI, here is how I setup :

```
private void ConfigureAuthentication(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            context.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
                })
                .AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
                    //options.Cookie.Name = ".MyApp";
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"];
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;

                    options.ClientId = configuration["AuthServer:ClientId"];
                    options.ClientSecret = configuration["AuthServer:ClientSecret"];

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.Scope.Add("role");
                    options.Scope.Add("email");
                    options.Scope.Add("phone");
                    options.Scope.Add("MyApp");

                    options.ClaimActions.MapAbpClaimTypes();
                });
        }
```

Comment: You don't mention if you're using Blazor client-side or server-side, but I recently wrote this about server-side OIDC with Blazor: https://mcguirev10.com/2019/12/15/blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect.html (and a couple related articles after that one).

Comment: Thanks @McGuireV10 , your sample help a lot, I'm working on this. But I noticed that in your sample, when we logout, we don't redirect to the desired page, we stay on the identity server. By example, if I wish to redirect to an "index.html" page, how can I do ? 

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To redirect back to your client app after logout from IDS4 by clicking link `Click here to return to the Interactive client ....` , you should set correct `PostLogoutRedirectUris` in client configuration :

```
new Client
{
    ....

    // where to redirect to after logout
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

     ....
},
```

In article from @McGuireV10 , he is using the identity server's demo server for testing , and use `interactive.confidential.short` client , you can't set that client's `PostLogoutRedirectUris` , so it will be `https://localhost:5001/signout-callback-oidc` by default . You can set your own identity server to test the scenario .

Comment: I tried the PostLogoutRedirectUris , I set it to http://localhost:5000/index.html , but it does not work. I have also try to return new RedirectResult("/index.html"); , but then I'm redirected but not loged out !

Comment: Please hang on the link to confirm the url after logout in Identity server

Comment: Hi @NanYu, what do you mean ? I set PostLogoutRedirectUris to the right URL, but it does seems to work ! Any idea to debug this ?

Comment: After clicking logout in your client app , user will be redirect to Identity server's logout page , there is one href link   shows `Click here to return to the Interactive client ....` , when clicking `here` , user will be redirect again to client app , the `PostLogoutRedirectUris ` is that url . checking that url and see whether it matches your client app

Answer (score 2):

You could try this way for SignOut. it should work.

```
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
    {
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            return SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = "/"
                },
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I compiled few different sources and this is my solution for .Net Core 6 MVC app:

1. Logout action in Account controller:

   ```
   public async Task Logout()
   {
       await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
       await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("OpenIdConnect");
   }
   ```
2. Additional config within Program.cs and builder.Services.AddAuthentication and AddOpenIdConnect section:

   ```
   options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect += context =>
   {
       context.Response.Redirect(context.Options.SignedOutRedirectUri);
       context.HandleResponse();

       return Task.CompletedTask;
   };
   ```
3. Updated [IdentityServer].[ClientPostLogoutRedirectUris] for the client looking like:

   https://localhost:7015/**signout-callback-oidc**

appsettings.json entry example:

```
"SignedOutRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7015/"
```

In my case main page of the website allows anonymous access and after logout that's where IDS redirects it.

Foot note. From what I read Microsoft changed something in .NET Core regarding how things work and people get signed out from their website but not from Identity Server.

Hope it's helpful to someone.